# Slim router argument issue

Tags: php, slim, slim-4

Simple code

```
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");
    return $response; });
```

When I am passing name like (client--side-?validation.pdf) as argument

Like:

```
http://localhost:8085/hello/client--side-?validation.pdf
```

I am getting output like:

> Hello, client--side-

Some characters like : ?, @, +, # etc having issue.

Slim will not return full name(client--side-?validation.pdf) as we passed.

Question:
**What will be the solution of this?**

Comment: You will need to escape the argument - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript

Comment: @NigelRen, possible to give sample code?

Comment: I assume you're generating those URLs in PHP. If that isn't the case please let us know.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález that file name is route path. not URLs. so urlencode/urldecode not work in this case

Comment: Have you tried?